# Use Datatables in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-5.4

Hy, I want to add pagination and search field on a table. I am using laravel 5.4 and a raw query due to the complexity because I have to extract data from too many tables also I am beginner in laravel. I have go through the docs and did many changes but unfortunately could not get desired result. I am getting error:

> (DataTables warning: table id=vendors - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7).

So far here is my code.

view file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vendors</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

       <table class="table table-bordered" id="vendors">
            <thead>
                <th> Card Name </th>
                <th> Phone </th>
                <th> Emails </th>
            </thead>                
        </table>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#vendors').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        "url": "{{ url('allvendor') }}",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"}
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "card_name" },
                        { "data": "phone" },
                        { "data": "email" }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller :

```
public function allvendor(Request $request)
{

    $vendors =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `bp` inner join pdbp on bp.id = pdbp.bp_id inner join ( SeLECT bid, GROUP_CONCAT(subc_name SEPARATOR ', ') as cat FROM sub_categories sc inner join `bp_categories` bc on sc.subc_cod = bc.subc_cod group by bid) categories on bp.id = categories.bid inner join ( SeLECT bid, GROUP_CONCAT(material SEPARATOR ', ') as mat FROM product_material pm inner join `bp_materials` bm on pm.material_cod = bm.mat_cod group by bid ) materials on bp.id = materials.bid inner join (SeLECT bid, GROUP_CONCAT(description SEPARATOR ', ') as certt FROM cert c inner join `bp_certificate` bcc on c.id = bcc.cid group by bid) certificate on bp.id = certificate.bid"));

    $columns = array( 
        0 =>'card_name', 
        1 =>'phone',
        2=> 'email',
    );

    $totalData = $vendors::count();

    $totalFiltered = $totalData; 

    $limit = $request->input('length');
    $start = $request->input('start');
    $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
    $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

    if(empty($request->input('search.value')))
    {            
        $posts = vendors::offset($start)
                     ->limit($limit)
                     ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                     ->get();
    } else {
        $search = $request->input('search.value'); 

        $posts =  vendors::where('card_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                        ->offset($start)
                        ->limit($limit)
                        ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                        ->get();

        $totalFiltered = vendors::where('card_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                         ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                         ->count();
    }

    $data = array();
    if(!empty($vendors))
    {
        foreach ($vendors as $vendor)
        {
            $nestedData['card_name'] = $vendor->card_name;
            $nestedData['phone'] = $vendor->phone;
            $nestedData['email'] = $vendor->email;

            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }

    $json_data = array(
                    "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),  
                    "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),  
                    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), 
                    "data"            => $data   
                );

    echo json_encode($json_data);       
}
```

What is wrong in my code?? Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs you linked to in the error message it is clearly described that the back end usually sends back any other status code than a 2XX.

> This occurs when jQuery falls into its error callback handler (this callback built into DataTables), which will typically occur when the server responds with anything other than a 2xx HTTP status

Please open up your developer console (F12) and inspect the request that is made to the back end. Maybe you got the route wrong? Maybe the back end returns a HTTP 5XX error.

You can also try navigating to the URL directly in your browser if it is a GET method route.